# How do I get my conda environment to recognize my GPU?

Tags: python, pytorch, anaconda, gpu

I'm pretty new to this and I'm wondering how do I get my conda environment to be able to recognize my GPU? Purpose is for me to emulate the Linux environment on my windows 10 device. I'm using the Anaconda prompt.

I'm following the instructions in this set up guide : https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/4-steps-to-install-anaconda-and-pytorch-onwindows-10-5c9cb0c80dfe

But when I run the `torch.cuda.is_available()` it returns "false"

[image: screenshot problem]

Not sure where I'm going wrong, would appreciate any help on how to get it to show "true" instead.

Comment: What GPU do you have in your computer?

Comment: It's a NVIDIA RTX A3000 on my computer :) @James

Comment: You may need to install a fresh driver from NVidia.  One of my computers occasionally gets a driver install from the vender and it breaks using CUDA.

Comment: how do I know which driver to install? @James

Comment: Go here: https://www.nvidia.com/download/index.aspx, select your card and operating system.  If your card is not listed, pick the next closest in the same line (i.e. A4000) as they share drivers across product lines.  Download and install

Answer (score 1):

Check your CUDA version. Not all the version of CUDA supports official pytorch. Check the official website of [pytorch](https://pytorch.org/)